# Gitlab Continuous Integration Meteor

Tags: meteor, continuous-integration, gitlab, fedora

I've just start a project and I want to have a continuous integration environment on Gitlab.
I pushed a simple meteor project and it works fine on my local machine.
I wrote this on my gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: fedora:24

before_script:
  - dnf install tar npm python gyp gcc-c++ mongodb -y
  - dnf group install "Development Tools" -y
  - curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
  - meteor npm install

stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha-phantomjs --allow-superuser
```

It works well but when the pipeline reach the test line it stucks on **Started proxy** and never pass from that point.

I've also tried with several docker image for Meteor but none of that works.

**UPDATE**

I changed the docker base image for node:4.2.2 and now shows the next error.

```
Looks like MongoDB doesn't understand your locale settings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

It seems that there's a problem related to the language working with MongoDB.
Just adding the following lines the project now build succesfully on GitLab.

```
image: node:4.2.2

before_script:
  - apt-get update -y
  - apt-get install locales -y
  - locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
  - localedef -i en_GB -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8
  - dpkg-reconfigure locales
  - echo export LC_ALL=C >> ~/.bashrc
  - source ~/.bashrc
  - curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh
  - meteor npm install
```